# Let $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ and let $\phi$ be an epimorphism from $G$ to a group $H$.

Tags: group-theory

Hi: Let $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ and let $\phi$ be an epimorphism from $G$ to a group $H$. Let $A\neq 1$ be a normal subgroup of $H$ that is contained in $N^\phi$. Then $A^{\phi^{-1}}\cap N\neq 1$.

I can't understand this assertion. If $A^{\phi^{-1}}\cap N=1$ then $1=(A^{\phi^{- 1}}\cap N)^\phi \leq A\cap N^\phi=A$ and I don't get a contradiction. Why the assertion? The author ends proving $N^\phi=1$ or $N^\phi$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $H$.

Comment: Hi. Can you explain what $N^\phi$ means?

Comment: @ε-δ From context, I assume it is $\phi(N)$, that is, the image of $N$ under $\phi$.

Answer (score 3):

By hypothesis $A$ contains at least two elements, each of which is the image of an element of $N$ under $\varphi$ (since $A\subseteq\varphi[N]$), so $\varphi^{-1}[A]$ must contain at least two distinct elements of $N$.

Comment: It should be noted that this proof does not use the fact that $A$ is normal, $N$ is normal, or that $N$ is minimal normal. Or, for that matter, that $A$ and $N$ are subgroups, or that $G$ is a group.

Comment: Thanks. I see. $a\in A$, $a=\varphi(n)$, $\varphi(n)\in A$, $n\in \varphi^{-1}(A)$. I wanted to reason with sets, but it seems one should reason with elements.

Comment: @stf91: You’re welcome. Yes, in this case that really does make it easier.